# Activate a window using its Window ID

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

How would I programmatically activate i.e move-to-front-and-focus a window on macOS (not belonging to my app) given its `Window ID`. My app would run with user granted Accessibility permissions etc.

Surprisingly, none of the functions described on the [Quartz Window Services page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services) seem to do that.

Am using Swift currently, but am open to using Objective-C, AppleScript or whatever.

EDIT:

I don't want to bring to front all windows of the parent app - only the specific that matches the window ID.

Edit:

I know that the `NSWindow` type is only meant to refer to windows of the current process, but is there no class that represents windows owned by external apps? Like we have `NSRunningApplication` to refer to any running app including external ones, I was expecting an API to deal all open windows (assuming the right permissions). Is there some class like `NSOpenWindow` or `CGWindow` buried somewhere?

Comment: Please be more specific, what is `Window ID` and how did you get it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/kcgwindownumber

Comment: The window ID is one of the required values present in the window information returned by `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()`

Comment: Is the parent app scriptable? Is the Accessibility API an option?

Comment: Yes, my app would run with user granted accessibility permissions if required. The windows I would want to activate could belong to any app.

Comment: @HimanshuP Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730859/controlling-osx-windows

Comment: Yes I have, it doesn't have any reference to Window IDs as far as I could tell.

Comment: Do you need `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` or can you get the windows using the Accessibility API or AppleScript?

Comment: For some reason using the Accessibility API's AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue() has been returning AXError.cannotComplete (using Swift). I found a couple of posts about this issue on StackOverflow with no answers.

Comment: It works if the app isn't sandboxed. [How to use Accessibility with sandboxed app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116095/how-to-use-accessibility-with-sandboxed-app)

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I'm trying to achieve the same.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find a way to switch to a specific window yet, but you can switch to the app that contains a specific window using this function:

```
func switchToApp(withWindow windowNumber: Int32) {
    let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.excludeDesktopElements, CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenOnly)
    let windowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
    guard let infoList = windowListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return }
    if let window = infoList.first(where: { ($0["kCGWindowNumber"] as? Int32) == windowNumber}), let pid = window["kCGWindowOwnerPID"] as? Int32 {
        let app = NSRunningApplication(processIdentifier: pid)
        app?.activate(options: .activateIgnoringOtherApps)
    }
}
```

It is probably usefull to switch by name as well:

```
func switchToApp(named windowOwnerName: String) {
    let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.excludeDesktopElements, CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenOnly)
    let windowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
    guard let infoList = windowListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return }

    if let window = infoList.first(where: { ($0["kCGWindowOwnerName"] as? String) == windowOwnerName}), let pid = window["kCGWindowOwnerPID"] as? Int32 {
        let app = NSRunningApplication(processIdentifier: pid)
        app?.activate(options: .activateIgnoringOtherApps)
    }
}
```

Example: `switchToApp(named: "OpenOffice")`

On my mac OpenOffice was started with a window with `kCGWindowNumber = 599`, so this has the same effect: `switchToApp(withWindow: 599)`

As far as I found out so far, your options seem to be to show the currently active window of the app, or to show all windows (using `.activateAllWindows` as activation option)

Comment: Is there a way to activate a specific window of the app? Example: Firefox is active and has 5 windows. I want to activate one in particular, thanks to its `kCGWindowNumber`.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for an Objective C solution:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <libproc.h>
#import <string.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <stdio.h>

bool activate_window_of_id(unsigned long wid) {
  bool success = false;
  const CGWindowLevel kScreensaverWindowLevel = CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGScreenSaverWindowLevelKey);
  CFArrayRef windowArray = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);
  CFIndex windowCount = 0;
  if ((windowCount = CFArrayGetCount(windowArray))) {
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < windowCount; i++) {
      NSDictionary *windowInfoDictionary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)((CFDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowArray, i));
      NSNumber *ownerPID = (NSNumber *)(windowInfoDictionary[(id)kCGWindowOwnerPID]);
      NSNumber *level = (NSNumber *)(windowInfoDictionary[(id)kCGWindowLayer]);
      if (level.integerValue < kScreensaverWindowLevel) {
        NSNumber *windowID = windowInfoDictionary[(id)kCGWindowNumber];
        if (wid == windowID.integerValue) {
          CFIndex appCount = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] count];
          for (CFIndex j = 0; j < appCount; j++) {
            if (ownerPID.integerValue == [[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] objectAtIndex:j] processIdentifier]) {
              NSRunningApplication *appWithPID = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] objectAtIndex:j];
              [appWithPID activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateAllWindows | NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
              char buf[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE];
              proc_pidpath(ownerPID.integerValue, buf, sizeof(buf));
              NSString *buffer = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
              unsigned long location = [buffer rangeOfString:@".app/Contents/MacOS/" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location;
              NSString *path = (location != NSNotFound) ? [buffer substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, location)] : buffer;
              NSString *app = [@" of application \\\"" stringByAppendingString:[path lastPathComponent]];
              NSString *index = [@"set index of window id " stringByAppendingString:[windowID stringValue]];
              NSString *execScript = [[index stringByAppendingString:app] stringByAppendingString:@"\\\" to 1"];
              char *pointer = NULL;
              size_t buffer_size = 0;
              NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
              FILE *file = popen([[[@"osascript -e \"" stringByAppendingString:execScript] stringByAppendingString:@"\" 2>&1"] UTF8String], "r");
              while (getline(&pointer, &buffer_size, file) != -1)
                [array addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:pointer]];
              char *error = (char *)[[array componentsJoinedByString:@""] UTF8String];
              if (strlen(error) > 0 && error[strlen(error) - 1] == '\n')
                error[strlen(error) - 1] = '\0';
              if ([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:error] isEqualToString:@""])
                success = true;
              [array release];
              free(pointer);
              pclose(file);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  CFRelease(windowArray);
  return success;
}
```

Note, unlike Daniel's answer, this will not just bring the specified application's windows to the front, it will also make sure the specific window whose id matches the one specified will be the topmost out of that app's collection of windows. It will return true on success, and false on failure. I noticed it brings to front for some apps but not for others. I'm not sure why. The code it is based on does not work as advertised for its original purpose. Although, it did help me a lot to get working all the stuff I needed to answer this question. [The code my answer is based on can be found here](https://gist.github.com/matthewreagan/2f3a30b8b229e9e2aa7c). Ignore the original usage.

Comment: This seems to works, but it will prompt `MyApp wants to access control AppName. Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in AppName, and to perform action within that app`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if there is any way around that. Apple pretty much restricts all their third party developers from doing all kinds of important IPC that involves gui manipulation, and it's annoying because they do it to gain trust from their users to make it look like they care at all about the user and their privacy and personal protection, when they violate your personal space and know everything you do on your mac. It's only ok to be "invasive" when you are apple apparently.

Comment: For those who may not want to run osascript can look into NSAppleScript and have it run the script directly from your app as a singular app/process. Although running via osascript is probably safer as it won't crash or have undefined behavior whenever applescript has internal changes done to it after an OS update.