# Is there a way to get info on an active window in OSX?

Tags: macos, quartz

Is their a way to get information for an active / selected window (coordinates) and resize it in OSX (Objective-C or Swift). Similar to the way Cinch does it?
http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/

Comment: Just to be clear, you’re talking about a window belonging to a process other than your own, right?

Comment: Yes ie, xcode, itunes, etc

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730859/controlling-osx-windows?rq=1).